# why does interface show on ifconfig

Tags: networking, redhat, ifconfig

I bought up a vlan interface by running ifup on my ifcfg-vlan10 file, now when I do ifdown the ip connection goes down, however the device vlan10 is still visible in ifconfig. Why is that the case and how do I get rid of it from ifconfig?

Comment: have you tried to remove the configuration file from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts ?

Comment: no unfortunately it doesn't disappear from ifconfig if I "rm" the file ifcfg-vlan10 in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts.

Comment: Why do you want it to disappear?

Comment: well my understanding is that is shouldn't be there if it's not active. Typically my experience has been if the interface is active (or up) it will display in ifconfig, for any other interfaces you need to run "ifconfig -a" to display the remainder. In any case since I've deleted the dev by running "ip delete dev vlan10" and I've down'ed the interface via ifdown, I can't see how it should be available.

Answer (score 1):

Does [vconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vconfig) do what you want ?

```
vconfig rem vlan10
```

or similar.

Comment: no, it's still there after running vconfig, although vconfig said: Removed VLAN -:vlan10:-. I just don't get what is ifconfig showing.

Comment: running the following shows it is present still: cat /proc/net/vlan/vlan10